# How can I get the full content of a Word Document?

Tags: visual-c++, c#-4.0, vsto, office-addins

I have reviewed several ways to obtain access to the content of a Document in C# but no matter how much I search, I cannot find a way that truly takes all the information within it, so far I can only get it to take the "Paragraph" or the written content, there are Is there any way to take everything including the configuration within the Document, such as the header, page layout, titles, indexes, images and so on?

`I have somethign like this
// new open Document

Word.Range range = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Range();

// Extract the text

StreamReader sl = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Este es el sheets para word.docx");

// I have troubles keeping the format of the origilan DOC

range.InsertAfter( new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Este es el sheets para word.docx"));
`